# Is it safe to pass function pointers as arguments to dll functions and invoke them from inside of the dll?

Tags: dll, memory-management, function-pointers

I would like to pass some (dll or not) function pointers as arguments to some dll functions and call them from inside of the dll. I wonder if it is safe because I have found an information on http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r10.cbcpx01/fpref.htm that:

*In DLL code, it is assumed that a function pointer points to a function descriptor. A function pointer call is made by first obtaining the function address through dereferencing the pointer; and then, branching to the function entry. When a non-DLL function pointer is passed to DLL code, it points directly to the function entry. An attempt to dereference through such a pointer produces an undefined function address. The subsequent branching to the undefined address may result in an exception.*

Does this rule apply to Visual Studio and other compilers as well?

What precisely I am trying to do is to solve the problem of memory allocation and deallocation between various dll and non-dll functions. My idea is to pass two function pointers - for common allocation and deallocation functions - to every dll in some initialization (e.g. Initialize(&malloc, &free)) and then do all memory management using these common and thus always compatible functions.

Comment: The referenced article is not for Windows. Exported functions were only special in Win16.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not true. DLL code treats function pointers in exactly the same way as non-DLL code. If that were not the case, one could not use standard library functions like qsort() (which expects a function pointer argument) within a DLL.

Answer (score 6):

Passing function pointers to a DLL has been done for generations.

All the callback functions used in GUI programming (for example progress bars update) use function pointers.

When developing using WIN32, is there a reason you want to use function pointers to malloc/free?  Why are you not simply using malloc/free directly?

That is how I have always done it in the past. Not that this guarantees it's the correct way.
In fact, you might take that as an indication that it's the worst possible way :)

Comment: "Why are you not simply using malloc/free directly?"
- because using 'free' in one DLL on memory 'malloced' in a different DLL most often causes crashing.

Comment: I fail to see how providing a level of indirection would fix that, unless you have your own memory management. I haven't run across issues of crash when malloc/free from different DLLs as long as you don't do a double free.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx

The additional level of indirection provides access to single, shared (between all dlls) functions for memory management.

Comment: The particular state here is if one of the dlls is linked with a static version of the CRT that doesn't match the (static or dynamic) version of the CRT used by the EXE, crash.