# Passing Member Function Pointers Between Modules

Tags: c++

Just a curiosity question!  [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) seems to suggest that member function pointers are in fact different sizes pending compiler and compile options used, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653697/is-it-safe-to-pass-function-pointers-as-arguments-to-dll-functions-and-invoke-the) seems to suggest that function pointers are passed just fine between modules, so what about member function pointers?  I mean with all the hassles that are already presented in passing data between modules it would seem rather silly to even attempt this?  Or what about scenarios involving static libraries?  If two different compilers are used am I wrong to assume that any scenario involving the passing of a member function pointer would be fruitless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use two different compilers, then unless they have compatible ABI (application binary interface), you cannot sensibly mix-and-match any object code created by them, whether or not member function pointers are involved.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the extent of incompatibility of compilers.  I guess this http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?threadid=497483 was the question I should have asked.

Answer (score 1):

Member function pointers are quite different beasts from function pointers.  They must encode not only the function pointer to the member function, but must also encode the the correct type for the member function, so that the run-time knows how to call the member-function.  This is very dependent on how the compiler implements classes, and that implementation certainly changes between compiler vendors, and often changes within compilers based on how the compiler is invoked.

Comment: Hi TMG. FYI, they do not necessarily encode the correct type, but rather (in the case of MS C++ anyway) the offset calculation to map the address point of the object they are called upon to the address point of the callee, as well as which virtual or non-virtual function to call.  For a pointer to member function of a class with virtual inheritance, this can require a PMF that spans several words of memory.

Comment: @Jan: Though not a token or pointer representing a type, all of that information is related to the types the PMF is used on; significantly, it's all strongly dependent on how that particular compiler implements the machinery for user types.